# Using jquery to check if radio was changed

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I was trying to trigger an event using jquery radio button change but it wont even do an alert, I have the following on jsfiddle. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/nr16jvfr

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
    $("p").css("color":"red");
else
    $("p").css("color":"black");
});
```

Comment: Did you check console? There are syntax errors. It has to be `("color", "red")`

Comment: You have a syntax error, you should use `,` not `:` to separate parameters when calling a method. First step to debugging any JS error is to check the console.

Comment: Have your console open at all times! `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : `

Comment: ohh, console, that would have been good to check first, thx

Comment: That is a radio button not a checkbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the comma, colon issue, because you're using a radio button, you should be checking for a `click` rather than a `change` in my opinion. I've updated your JSFiddle to something that checks for the click, the index of the clicked radio, and then changes the color appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/nr16jvfr/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try like below...

In html

```
 <p>Something here</p>
 <input type="radio" name="md" id="r"/>r
 <input type="radio" name="md" id="b"/>b
```

In JQuery

```
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(e){

        if($("#r").is(":checked"))
           $("p").css("color","red");
        else if($("#b").is(":checked"))
           $("p").css("color","black");
  });
```

Here is the fiddle...
    http://jsfiddle.net/nr16jvfr/5/